# Monte Carlo Approximation of $\int_0^1\int_0^x x^2y dy dx$

Tags: integration, monte-carlo

I am trying to evaluate the integral $I=\int_0^1\int_0^x x^2y \cdot dydx$ using the Monte Carlo approach. Therefore I generate $n$ random x values for $x_i\in (0, 1)$ and then generate $n$ random y values for $y_i\in (0, x_i)$. I attempted this in matlab as follows:

```
n=100000;
s=0;

for i=1:n 
x=rand(1,1); 
y=rand(1,1) * x;
s = s + x^2 * y; 
end 

I = s/n;
```

This gives $I\approx 0.125...$ however, the integral can be easily evaluated analytically to obtain $I= 0.1$. I'm really at a loss as for where the overestimation is coming from.

Comment: Why is $y \in (0, \sqrt{x})$?

Comment: @YuriyS Oops that should be x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to find $\displaystyle\int^b_a f(y)\; dy$ by Monte Carlo integration then you want $(b-a)$ times the average of the sample values of $f(y)$ with $y$ drawn uniformly from that interval

So $\displaystyle \int_0^1\int_0^x x^2y \; dy \;dx = \int_0^1 x^2 \left(\int_0^x y \; dy\right) \; dx$ could be modelled by adapting your code to

```
n=100000;
s=0;

for i=1:n 
x=rand(1,1); 
y=rand(1,1) * x;
s = s + (1-0) * x^2 * (x-0) * y; 
end 

I = s/n;
```

Comment: Ah I was completely missing the (b-a) portion. This would explain why everything was working fine when I had swapped my y boundary to 0->1

Answer (score 4):

Your region of integration is a right triangle that is half of the square $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ below the line $y=x$.  As such you should have $y \in [0,x]$.  However, you should not take $y=rand*x$ as that will have points much more densely packed for small $x$.  You should just throw random numbers for each of $x$ and $y$ then throw out any where $y \gt x$.

Comment: That seems to give about $0.2$

Comment: This was definitely a problem although it appears to not have resolved the issue entirely as I also finding the same result as Henry.

Comment: Are you just averaging the numbers you get?  You need to multiply by the area, which is $1/2$.

Comment: I was just averaging the values of the function at the random x and y values. It's weird because it works fine when the boundaries for the integrals are fixed.

Comment: It shouldn't work when the boundaries are fixed unless the area is $1$.  The integral is the average value of the integrand times the area of integration.  If you do $\int_0^21\ dx$ the average value is $1$ but the integral is $2$.